# UDP receivefrom or sendto not working

Tags: c#, networking, udp

I'm just learning how to program networking. I'm trying to make a udp system using sockets instead of the udpclient class (something I couldn't find much information on through searches).

The server receives the messages from the client and prints them, but the client gets stuck on the receivefrom where it blocks the thread. 
What am I doing wrong here?

My server code:

```
Socket sck = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );

IPEndPoint _IPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, 55566 );
EndPoint _EndPoint = _IPEndPoint;
sck.Bind( _IPEndPoint );

byte[] buffer = new byte[ 255 ];
int rec = sck.ReceiveFrom( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref _EndPoint );
Array.Resize( ref buffer, rec );
string clientIP = Encoding.Default.GetString( buffer );
Console.WriteLine( "Received: {0}", clientIP );

buffer = new byte[ 255 ];
rec = sck.ReceiveFrom( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref _EndPoint );
Array.Resize( ref buffer, rec );
int clientPort = BitConverter.ToInt32( buffer, 0 );
Console.WriteLine( "Received: {0}", clientPort );

buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes( "Hello " + clientIP );
sck.SendTo( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(clientIP), clientPort) ); // never gets received

sck.Close();


Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit();
```

and client code:

```
Socket sck = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp );
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Parse( "127.0.0.1" ), 55566 );
sck.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Parse( "127.0.0.1" ), 0 ) );
EndPoint endPoint = ipEndPoint;

string msg = new Func<string>( () =>
{
    var host = Dns.GetHostEntry( Dns.GetHostName() );
    foreach ( var ip in host.AddressList )
    {
        if ( ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork )
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    throw new Exception( "Local IP Address Not Found!" );
} )();
byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes( msg );
Console.WriteLine( "sending IP" );
sck.SendTo( msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipEndPoint );

msgBuffer = BitConverter.GetBytes( ( (IPEndPoint) sck.LocalEndPoint ).Port );
Console.WriteLine( "sending port" );
sck.SendTo( msgBuffer, 0, msgBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ipEndPoint );

byte[] buffer = new byte[ 255 ];
Console.WriteLine( "receiving message" );
int rec = sck.ReceiveFrom( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint ); // gets stuck here

Array.Resize( ref buffer, rec );

Console.WriteLine( "Received: " + Encoding.Default.GetString( buffer ) );

sck.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to say for sure without knowing more about the environment in which you're testing. But most likely, the client is sending the wrong IP address and/or port.

The server should never rely on the client itself to report its address anyway. The server will know that information from the `ReceiveFrom()` method, and should *only* use the information from that method to send data back.

For example:

```
EndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

rec = sck.ReceiveFrom( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref clientEndPoint);
Array.Resize( ref buffer, rec );
int clientPort = BitConverter.ToInt32( buffer, 0 );
Console.WriteLine( "Received: {0}", clientPort );

buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes( "Hello " + clientIP );
sck.SendTo( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, clientEndPoint); // never gets received
```

Of course, keep in mind that UDP is unreliable. All of the following are true when using UDP:

1. Any given datagram may never arrive.
2. Any given datagram may be received more than once.
3. The datagrams sent may arrive in any order, regardless of the order in which they were sent.

Naturally, these characteristics can wreak havoc with code like what you've written, where the code assumes data will be sent and received in some specific order and without any rearranging or duplication.